# draggable rows using ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5.6

i'm here trying to make a draggable rows for table and update the change in the database, so i follow on tutorial the drag and drop works fine but the changes not save in the database. 
this is the tutorial i'm follow
https://shareurcodes.com/blog/create-drag-and-droppable-datatables-using-jquery-ui-sortable-in-laravel

and here my codes

searchController

```
class SearchController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // $customers = Customer::all();
        $customers = Customer::orderBy('order', 'ASC') - > select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone') - > get();
        return view('search.search', compact('customers'));
    }

    public function updateOrder(Request $request) {
        $customers = Customer::all();
        //$customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);

        foreach($customers as $customer) {
            $customer - > timestamps = false;
            $id = $customer - > id;
            foreach($request - > order as $order) {
                if ($order['id'] == $id) {
                    $customer - > update(['order' => $order['id']]);
                }
                //if($order['id'] = $id){
                //                    $customer->update($request->all());
                //                }
            }
        }
        return response('Update Successfully', 200);
    }
}
```

search.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#table").DataTable();
        $("#tablecontents").sortable({
            items: "tr",
            //   cursor: 'move',
            opacity: 0.6,
            update: function() {
                sendOrderToServer();
            }
        });

        function sendOrderToServer() {
            let order = [];
            $('tr.row1').each(function(index) {
                order.push({
                    id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
                    position: index + 1
                });

            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "{{ url('search.search') }}",
                data: {
                    order: order,
                    _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.status == "success") {
                        console.log(response);
                    } else {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

route

```
Route::post('search/search','searchController@updateOrder');
```

this is the table

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->integer('order');
        $table->timestamps();
```

when i drag and drop this error in the console

jquery.min.js:4 POST http://adminproject.test/search.search 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing ajax route like below

```
url: "{{ url('search/search') }}"
```

Comment: its the same, nothing change

Answer (score 0):

it was a silly mistake,

just change the url in javascript 
from

```
url: "{{ url('search.search') }}",
```

to

```
 url: "{{ url('search') }}",
```